# When receiving SIGINT, does bash also quit other commands, besides loops (for or while)?

Tags: bash, signals, sigint

From bash manual

> When Bash receives a SIGINT, it breaks out of any executing loops.

When receiving SIGINT, does bash also quit other commands, besides loops (for or while)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the bash manual:

> When `bash` is interactive, in the absence of any  traps,  it  ignores
>          `SIGTERM` (so  that  `kill 0` does not kill an interactive shell), and
>          `SIGINT` is caught and handled (so that the `wait` builtin is interruptible).

Yes, bash quits builtins when it receives `SIGINT`. You can verify that with `wait` or `read` (`read` from a large file with no newlines will give you time to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>). `wait` in particular needs to deal with `SIGINT` correctly, [as per POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wait.html) (along with all other signals it can come across).

Comment: Thanks. Besides loop and builtins, does bash quit anything else?

Comment: What else could it quit?

Comment: like other control flow contructs such as "if" and external commands? Why are they not mentioned?

Comment: External commands deal with `SIGINT` themselves (the shell *is* informed if an external command was killed by a signal, but it deals with that by interpreting the information given by `wait(2)` or `waitpid(2)`, not by installing a signal handler). `if` etc. run at a point in time, so there’s not much point in making them interruptible.